# If statement searches values only in specific order

Tags: python-3.x

I am loading two JSON files and iterate them in order to replace values from of the JSON's using references from the other.

```
{"Target":{
 "TV_1":{
                "id":"001_101_001",
                "query_name":"tvchview",
                "param":{"$source":"tv","$channel":["RTL","rrr"]},
                "target_group_type":"multiple",
                "mapping_list":{}
            },
  "TV_2":{
                "id":"001_101_003",
                "query_name":"tvch_1hr",
                "param":{"$source":"tv"},
                "target_group_type":"multiple",
                "mapping_list":{}
            }}}




{"Target_queries": {
"tvchview":{
             "name":"tvchview",
             "description":"Select panelists that have watched a tv channel at least one time.",
             "sql":"SELECT DISTINCT pnr, channel AS value FROM $source WHERE channel IN ( $channel ) AND slice_start >= $startdate AND slice_start <= $enddate ;"
               },
  "tvch_1hr":{
             "name":"tvch_1hr",
             "description":"Select panelists that have watched tv channels for at least one hour.",
             "sql":"SELECT pnr, channel AS value FROM $source WHERE slice_start >= $startdate AND slice_start <= $enddate AND duration >= 3600 AND channel != '-' GROUP BY pnr, channel;"
              }}}
```

My code works when the JSON files look like this, but when I switch the places of TV_1 and TV_2 (TV_2 goes in the place of TV_1) my code doesnt return anything, meaning it doesnt match the two dicts by `name` and `query_name`.

This is the part of code where i replace the values:

```
for (k, v), (k1, v1) in zip(params_to_replace.items(), queries.items()):
    if v1['name'] in v['query_name']:
        params = v['param'] 
        split_queries = v1['sql'].split()
        final_string = ' '.join(str(params.get(word, word)) for word in split_queries)
        final_string = re.sub(r'(\[)|(\])', '', final_string)
        replaced_queries[k] = final_string
    else:
        pass
```

`v1['name']` is where the name of the queries are (`"name":"tvchview"`) and `v['query_name']` is the names, but in the other JSON (`"query_name":"tvchview"`). When I switch again the structure of the queries it works again. Somehow the if statement search only when the order of the query names matches on both files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `zip` statement, which only joins two entries. Instead you want to test all possible combinations. For this you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

The corrected code:

```py
import re
import itertools
params_to_replace = {
    "TV_2": {
        "id": "001_101_003",
        "query_name": "tvch_1hr",
        "param": {"$source": "tv"},
        "target_group_type": "multiple",
        "mapping_list": {}
    },
 "TV_1":{
                "id":"001_101_001",
                "query_name":"tvchview",
                "param":{"$source":"tv","$channel":["RTL","rrr"]},
                "target_group_type":"multiple",
                "mapping_list":{}
            },
}

queries = {
"tvchview":{
             "name":"tvchview",
             "description":"Select panelists that have watched a tv channel at least one time.",
             "sql":"SELECT DISTINCT pnr, channel AS value FROM $source WHERE channel IN ( $channel ) AND slice_start >= $startdate AND slice_start <= $enddate ;"
               },
  "tvch_1hr":{
             "name":"tvch_1hr",
             "description":"Select panelists that have watched tv channels for at least one hour.",
             "sql":"SELECT pnr, channel AS value FROM $source WHERE slice_start >= $startdate AND slice_start <= $enddate AND duration >= 3600 AND channel != '-' GROUP BY pnr, channel;"
              }}

replaced_queries = {}

for (k, v), (k1, v1) in itertools.product(params_to_replace.items(), queries.items()):
    if v1['name'] in v['query_name']:
        params = v['param']
        split_queries = v1['sql'].split()
        final_string = ' '.join(str(params.get(word, word)) for word in split_queries)
        final_string = re.sub(r'(\[)|(\])', '', final_string)
        replaced_queries[k] = final_string
    else:
        pass

print(replaced_queries)
```

> > > {'TV_2': "SELECT pnr, channel AS value FROM tv WHERE slice_start >= $startdate AND slice_start <= $enddate AND duration >= 3600 AND channel != '-' GROUP BY pnr, channel;", 'TV_1': "SELECT DISTINCT pnr, channel AS value FROM tv WHERE channel IN ( 'RTL', 'rrr' ) AND slice_start >= $startdate AND slice_start <= $enddate ;"}